# unable to get original array back after filter removed in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have an array in my component and based on the searchString i am filtering the array of items. and it is working fine.
if user removes the characters from the search field i want to show all the records again. but i am unable to show all records again when clearing the items from the search field.

please see below code.

```
 this.filterServ.filterData.subscribe(searchData => {
         if (Object.keys(searchData).length != 0) {
            console.log('component', searchData);
           this.cardData = this.cardData.filter((project) => {
               let name = project.Name.toLowerCase();
               if (name.includes(searchData.searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                  return true;
               }
            });
           console.log('filterd data', this.cardData);
         }
      });
```

Comment: Don't overwrite `cardData`. Create another property and assign it the `this.cardData.filter()` values. Display this filtered values in the view. (Not familiar with angular but there must be a way to create a computed property)

Comment: keep original array as it is and add filter items new filter array

Answer (score 1):

You already mutated the `cardData`. Therefore, you can't revert it back.

The solution is to create another property, for example you can name it `displayData`.

Then you can do like:

```
this.displayData = this.cardData.filter((project) => {
```

and instead of using `cardData` on the template, use `displayData` instead

Comment: how to do it with out creating new array or new variable, because i am passing this to other component as Input

Comment: You can pass the displayData as well

Comment: if  i pass display data in child component duplicates will be there? but i need a solution with out taking help of new array or new variable? because i am using BehaviorSubject also to listen changes from the search field

Comment: I'm sure it is not possible, once it is changed, it could never be back, unless you hold the last value somewhere, that why we need either to clone the original value or create a cloned one to use

Answer (score 0):

You should take copy of array data before filtering, and return the original array if input text is empty.

```
    private originalData;

    this.originalData = this.cardData.slice();
    this.filterServ.filterData.subscribe(searchData => {
         if (Object.keys(searchData).length != 0) {
            console.log('component', searchData);
           this.cardData = this.originalData.filter((project) => {
               let name = project.Name.toLowerCase();
               if (name.includes(searchData.searchString.toLowerCase())) 
               {
                  return true;
               }
            });
           console.log('filterd data', this.cardData);
         }
      });
```

Comment: how to do it with out creating new array or new variable, because i am passing this to other component as Input

Comment: you can define originalData as private variable array;

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya, you neen't make a copy of originalData, make : this.cardData=this.originalData.filter(...)

Answer (score 0):

Declare field `filterData` and bind this field in the template.

```
this.filterServ.filterData.subscribe(searchData => {
         if (Object.keys(searchData).length != 0) {
            console.log('component', searchData);
           this.filterData= this.cardData.filter((project) => {
               let name = project.Name.toLowerCase();
               if (name.includes(searchData.searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                  return true;
               }
            });
           console.log('filterd data', this.cardData);
         }
      });
```

Hope this help!

Comment: how to do it with out creating new array or new variable, because i am passing this to other component as Input